# Qt как связать сигналы между собой

Tags: qt, сигналы-слоты

Возможно ли прописать в `QObject::connect()` вызов слота при выполнении условия такого вида:

```
if (sig1WasSent && sig2WasSent) 
    вызов слота
```

Т.е. мне необходимо вызвать слот, когда были посланы оба сигнала.

Comment: Такое нельзя сделать, но можете завести флаг, по которому будет код в слоте будет выполняться. А можете объяснить для чего вам такое?

Comment: @gil9red Большое спасибо за подсказку. 
Мне это надо было для перемотки трека в mp3 плеере. Т.к. slider должен показывать и текущий момент трека, то он изменяется (исопльзую слот setValuе() по сигналу от mediaplayer::valueChanged() ). Для перемотки хотел создать условие, что трек перематывается лишь когда пользователь изменил значение.

Comment: Игрался с QMediaPlayer'ом и там не понадобилось так исхитряться: https://github.com/gil9red/grab_seasonvar . Для аудио тоже: https://github.com/gil9red/audio_player_vk (теперь не работает)

Comment: @gil9red Премного благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы не оставался открытым: так делать невозможно